# Cant change buttons picture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 3 buttons:

*.h: (all are with filled circle, that means that they are **assigned**)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *AllButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *FavouritesButton;
```

*.m:

```
@synthesize FavouritesButton;
@synthesize AllButton;
```

and code:

```
AllButton.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_top_icon_active-1.png"]; //image exists
```

And it doesn't change the image! On other View i did the same and they work - what the hell?

I even tried to set not existing image:

```
AllButton.imageView.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"oisagiowgiow.png"]; //image doesn't exist - but no errors or crashes
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Use the property called setBackgroundImage or setImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
[AllButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"list_top_icon_active-1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and make sure your button type is custom

Comment: You are correct, but why the hell my code works on other controller?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 140, 240, 30);
[button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: no UIButtonTypeRoundedRect need to custom

Answer (score 0):

You should assign image to UIButton the following way:

```
[allButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"oisagiowgiow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```